# Email Send Activity in Automation Studio is not able to send Emails to duplicate Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

We are trying to implement an event notification system in SFMC. When a subscriber subscribes for an event he is getting a confirmation email. **3 days prior to the event I need to send a Reminder email to all the confirmed participants.**
A single subscriber can subscribe for more than one event that can take place on the same day. In my target data extension, for Reminder Emails, in the Send relationship, I am mentioning SubscriberKey relates to SubscriberKey in All subscribers.

My target DE have multiple entries in it with the same Subscriber Key but for different events. The email is only getting sent for only one Entry for a particular subscriber key.

Is this some feature in Automation studio that prevents multiple emails to be sent to a subscriber in a Target DE?
Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: When configuring your send activity you find a checkbox "deduplicate by email address" in the audience selection tab. Make sure this is unchecked. When checked it will send to the first record with the same email address and ignore all others after that.

Comment: Thanks....It worked